# To what extent are garden/yard animal questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

A [recent question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4499/nesting-box-cleaning) gives an the opportunity to define our scope just a bit more.

How much should questions surrounding birds (and the feeding, housing etc of such) and other (potentially) beneficial animals be on topic? To what extent does our scope stretch and where are the boundaries.

Is this particular question on topic and if it is what are the limits of it's topicality?

Answer (score 4):

I was very surprised when I saw 3 votes, 0 flags and only one close vote and wondered if there was something there that I was missing. This question (and such questions) should be 100% **off-topic** because feeding and nesting habits of birds it's not gardening but ornithology.

It seemed like the OP was trying to use [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4499/109) as a justification for asking his, but the other one is clearly within scope because it asks what plants/landscaping structures attract birds in general. You didn't need to be an expert in ornithology to be able to answer that question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it was out of scope but it was a question I was interested in knowing the answer. As an urban gardener I spend hours in the winter planning to make the garden attractive to wildlife.

Also, I remember thinking, "If not here, then where?".  I don't think there is a middle ground on scope, flexible interpretation usually means anything goes after a while.

So, out of scope it is.